# Docker Lambda Image: Could not find or load main class com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda

Tags: java, docker, aws-lambda

I built a Docker Lambda Image using the following DockerFile

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi:8.1 as base

RUN yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y sudo bash curl wget man-db nano bash-completion
RUN yum install -y java-11-openjdk-devel
RUN java -version


ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/java", "-cp", "./*", "com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda" ]
CMD ["optimizerMarsExecutor.OptimizerMarsExecutorFunction::handleRequest"]
```

After building and tagging the image, I executed the Lambda function with the following commands

```
docker run -p 9000:8080 mars-console-linux-image
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{"payload":"hello world!"}'
```

Following the executiong of the commands above, I received the following errors:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What command do you use to build the image before you run it? And what does the `"-cp", "./*` in the ENTRYPOINT do?

Comment: @b01 The command I use is docker build -t mars-console-linux-image .   According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-image.html#java-image-clients, the ENTRYPOINT value is the module that you want the Docker container to run when it starts. In this case, the module is the runtime interface client.

Comment: You don't seem to have `COPY`ed a jar file or any other application code into the image.

Comment: I was more asking what `java -cp ./*` does, so I looked it up. 

`--class-path classpath, -classpath classpath, or -cp classpath`
Specifies a list of directories, JAR files, and ZIP archives to search for class files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In-order to resolve my issue, I had to modify my Dockerfile to the following

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/java:11


COPY OptimizerMarsExecutorFunction/build/classes/java/main/ ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY OptimizerMarsExecutorFunction/build/dependencies/* ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/lib/
COPY OptimizerMarsExecutorFunction/build/resources/* ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/resources/
CMD ["optimizerMarsExecutor.OptimizerMarsExecutorFunction::handleRequest"]
```

In addition to that, I had to add the following to my build.gradle

```
task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath
    into 'build/dependencies'
}
build.dependsOn copyDependencies
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're not installing the Runtime Interface Client.

See [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/blob/main/aws-lambda-java-runtime-interface-client/README.md) example from AWS.

There's a `pom.xml` in the local folder that's copied to the container image (`ADD pom.xml .`) before Maven is run (`RUN mvn ...`) to install the dependencies defined in the `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-serialization</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

Try replicating the example in that document and you should be successful.

Comment: I using gradle and I have the following                                                                        implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:1.2.2'
 implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-events:3.11.0'
 implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3' Would I need to add the java serialization dependency

Comment: I didn't see a `gradle build` anywhere in your Dockerfile. Presumably, you'll need to run that instead of Maven. Unsure about whether you need the the serialization dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with how your building the image.

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi:8.1 AS base

RUN yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y sudo bash curl wget man-db nano bash-completion
RUN yum install -y java-11-openjdk-devel
RUN java -version

# This should really be a directory under a non-root user. But we will use it for brevity.
RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app


# Copy all your classpath files into the container
COPY . .

# This command is long so use the shell form: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd
CMD /usr/bin/java \
    -cp /app \
    "com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda" \
    "optimizerMarsExecutor.OptimizerMarsExecutorFunction::handleRequest"
```